# Multiple GET methods match: select most specific

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, java-ee-7

I have a web service that looks like:

```
@Path("/ws")
public class Ws {
    @GET public Record getOne(@QueryParam("id") Integer id) { return record(id); }
    @GET public List<Record> getAll() { return allRecords(); }
}
```

The idea is that I can either call:

- `http://ws:8080/ws?id=1` to get a specific record
- `http://ws:8080/ws` to get all available records

However when I use the second URL, the first `@GET` method is called with a null `id`.

Is there a way to achieve what I want without using different paths?

<sub>I think this can be achieved with Spring using the `@RequestMapping(params={"id"})` and `@RequestMapping` annotations for the first and second methods respectively but I can't use Spring in that project.</sub>

Comment: Why not just implement a logic in your code that checks if the param is `null` and then return all?

Comment: @user432 the two methods don't have the same return type - I could return an `Object` I suppose it looks a bit messy...

Comment: What do you return? Could you return a list of one and a list of all?

Comment: @user432 Both your suggestions could work indeed. But I would prefer some "magic" annotation or configuration that does it automatically for me if that exists (maybe not).

Comment: I don't know of a way to specifically match the URL with a parameter to a different method so I would have gone with this design.

Comment: @user432 Thanks - feel free to post this as an answer - I'll leave the question open for now to see if somebody comes up with an alternative approach.

Comment: For REST-style services, you should map a specific request to your controller. I haven't come across anything that maps multiple request to one method. GET a record and GET all records should have different URL mapping. It's the uniqueness of the resource you are GETting. That's the REST. Think about Amazon Prime Instant Video for instance. When you select the Amazon Prime Instant video category, leave the search box empty, and press ENTER - do you see a simply URL pointing to AMAZON PRIME video or does it have a request string in it? Every request mapping should be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the path is the same, you cannot map it to a different method. If you change the path using REST style mapping

```
@Path("/ws")
public class Ws {
    @GET @Path("/{id}") public Response getOne(@PathParam("id") Integer id) { return Response.status(200).entity(record(id)).build(); }
    @GET public Response getAll() { return Response.status(200).entity(allRecords()).build(); }
```

then you should use:

- `http://ws:8080/ws/1` to get a specific record
- `http://ws:8080/ws` to get all available records